# Visual Studio: Break on variable change?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I have a member variable struct in a C++ class I'm debugging in Visual Studio 2008 Professional. I would like to break any time the struct changes. Is it possible to do this, or must I look for every possible point in the code it could change, and set breakpoints there?

Comment: Do you want to break at changes for _any instance_ of that `struct` or for _one particular_ instance?

Comment: (You might want to properly @address people to whom you're replying in comments, so that your answers are shown as such to them. I only came across this one by accident.) Then [MSN's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231149/visual-studio-break-on-variable-change/3231192#3231192) is what you need.

Answer (score 7):

If you can determine the address of the member, you can set a data breakpoint on it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx#BKMK_Set_a_data_change_breakpoint__native_C___only_

Comment: I don't think you even need the address to do that.

Comment: +1.  You need the address.  And you cannot watch the entire structure.

Comment: @rofly, strictly speaking, you can use a global symbol or an expression that evaluates to an address. But in the end, the processor can only set data breakpoints for addresses, so it has to be translatable to an address.

Comment: Link updated to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx#BKMK_Set_a_data_change_breakpoint__native_C___only_